# bash: get path to parent directory by name

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get the path to the nearest parent directory named `foo`:

```
/this/is/the/path/to/foo/bar/baz

yields

/this/is/the/path/to/foo
```

Any idea how I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using BASH string manipulation:

```
p='/this/is/the/path/to/foo/bar/baz'
name='foo'

r="${p%/$name/*}/$name"

echo "$r"
/this/is/the/path/to/foo
```

OR better would be to use:

```
p='/this/is/afoo/food/path/to/foo/bar/baz'
echo "${p/\/$name\/*/\/$name}"
/this/is/afoo/food/path/to/foo
```

[BASH FAQ Reference](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: The second solution works correctly for `p='/this/is/foo/the/path/to/afoo/bar/baz'`, unlike the first one.

Comment: Thanks @choroba, I corrected first one also for this case.

Comment: The above "better would be to use" won't work as we are not checking for a / character just before word "foo". The correct command would be: echo "${p/\/$name/*/\/$name}"

Comment: I'd consider linking to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 or http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe to give folks some guidance on the why/wherefore.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy great help. I also like: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html (from Mendel Cooper)

Comment: @ArunSangal, I strongly advise against using the ABS as a source; it's poorly maintained and often uses bad practices in its examples. In the freenode #bash IRC channel, we're often trying to help people unlearn bad habits they got from the ABS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This operation (using % sign) will remove anything after foo word (if it's in a variable **var** from the right side) then suffix it with foo.

```
echo ${var%/foo/*}foo
```

or

```
echo ${var/\/foo\/*/\/foo}
```

Removing *foo* (at last) from the above command will give the parent folder of first occurrence of foo folder. Including foo will give you the first foo folder as the parent.

**PS**: If there's no "/foo/" folder in the path, then, the above echo command will output whatever is the value of given path (i.e. $var as it's) aka it'll output a wrong output for your purpose **OR** it may work correctly only in case the given path i.e. $var is **/foo**).