# Bash command to find parent GOPATH

Tags: bash, shell, gopath

I am trying to write a script to process some code in a `GOPATH`.
The code may be nested multiple directories deep.

I'll be running my script in an environment where `GOPATH` doesn't exist.

What's a simple way in shell to find the `GOPATH` from a nested directory inside the `GOPATH`?

It works if I do something like this

```
GOAPTH=$(dirname $(dirname $(dirname $(dirname $(pwd)))))
```

or

```
GOPATH=$(cd ../../../../; pwd)
```

But it requires me to have to know how many levels I am nested.

Comment: What should be the characteristics of a directory being `GOPATH`?

Comment: Good point. For me my GOPATH is always called `go`. So my solution was to find a directory named `go` that has `src` in it.

Comment: Any particular reason for needing to compute the path as opposed to just setting it in environment and reading it from there? Seems to me this path won’t change very frequently.

Comment: @Timir yea that's probably a better way.

Answer (score -1):

With some help from [bash: get path to parent directory by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31119822/bash-get-path-to-parent-directory-by-name)

I came up with this:

```
GOPATH="${PWD%/go/src/*}/go"
```

It takes the current working directory path, trims anything at and after `/go/src`, and then ads `/go` to the end.

It seems like a simple way to do it.

Comment: This doesn't work if the GOPATH directory is not named `go`